# npx create-react-app says "Create React App requires Node 14 or higher. Please update your version of Node." even tho my node version is v16.16.0

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ubuntu, npm, create-react-app

I was trying to create a react app, but got following.

> $ npx create-react-app moose --template particles-typescript

> You are running Node 13.14.0. Create React App requires Node 14 or higher.

> Please update your version of Node.

This is the result for node -v.

> node -v

> v16.16.0

I have tried setting node 16 as node in use through nvm. still same issue.
what to do please help.

Comment: Can you check what the environment variable in your system for Node displays? Also, what version of npm do you use?

Comment: @OmerTal my npm version is 8.11.0 and when I run process.env.NODE_ENV in node shell it says undefined